# I'm unable to write the structure in a text file in C

Tags: c, structure, text-files, codeblocks, file-handling

I've made this program for a school project. It runs just fine except that I'm unable to write the data in text file as I desire. The file text that i get is as follows :

AJames y$¥   °› †løvúövÿÿÿÿ$   „þ`B-28  ®kt¼› €@ ° @     ¬þ` …tt¸?’tìþ`¢it   Mark $¥€@ €@     ° @ Àþ` øþ`Ìÿ` IT tÕÑþÿÿÿ  áD

I'm not strong in C and therefore, even after going through online forums, I'm unable to find a specific answer. The following is the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *fp, *ft;
  char tmp, choice;

  struct fee
 {     float r_no;
       char name[50];
       char add[50];
       char f_name[40];
       char stream[10];
       float d_fee;
  }f;
long int amount;
int flag;
long int total = 2000;
long int pending=0;
long int size;
char stream1[40];
float r_no1;

     fp=fopen("FEES.txt","w");
     if(fp==NULL)
     {
            puts("Cannot open file");
            exit(1);
     }

size = sizeof(f);
while(1)
{
     system("cls");

     printf("\n\t\tWelcome to Main Menu!!");

     printf("\n\t\t1. Student Detail");

     printf("\n\t\t2. Display Record");

     printf("\n\t\t3. Deposit Fee");

     printf("\n\t\t4. Pending Fee");

     printf("\n\t\t5. Delete Record");

     printf("\n\t\t0. Exit");

     printf("\n\n\tYour choice : ");
     fflush(stdin);
     choice = getche();
     switch(choice)
     {
            case '1':
            fseek(fp,10,SEEK_SET);
            tmp = 'Y';
            while((tmp == 'Y') || (tmp == 'y'))
            {
                        printf("\n\tEnter Roll No: ");
                        scanf("%f", &f.r_no);
                        printf("\n\tEnter Name: ");
                        scanf(" %s", f.name);
                        printf("\n\tEnter Address: ");
                        scanf(" %s", f.add);
                        printf("\n\tEnter Father Name: ");
                        scanf(" %s", f.f_name);
                        printf("\n\tEnter Deposited Fee: ");
                        scanf("%f", &f.d_fee);
                        printf("\n\tEnter Stream: ");
                        scanf(" %s", f.stream);
                        fwrite(&f, size, 1, fp);
                        printf("\nCreate Another Student Record(Y/N)");
                        tmp = getche();
            }
            break;

            case '2':
            system("cls");
            rewind(fp);
            printf("Roll No: \tName: \tAddress: \tFather's Name: \tStream: \tDeposited Fee: \tTotal Amount: ");
            while(fread(&f, size, 1, fp))
            printf("\n%d \t%s \t%s \t%s \t%s \t%f \t%ld", f.r_no, f.name, f.add, f.f_name, f.stream, f.d_fee, total);
            getch();
            break;

            case '3':
            tmp='Y';
            while(tmp=='Y' || tmp=='y')
            {
                        printf("\nEnter Roll Number to Check Balance");
                        scanf("%d", &r_no1);
                        printf("\nEnter the Stream");
                        scanf("%s", &stream1);
                        rewind(fp);
                        flag=0;
                        while(fread(&f, size, 1, fp))
                        {
                                    if((f.r_no==r_no1)&&(strcmp(f.stream,stream1)))
                                    {
                                        if(f.d_fee<=total)
                                        {
                                                flag=1;
                                                printf("\nEnter amount to Deposit");
                                                scanf("%ld", &amount);
                                                f.d_fee = f.d_fee + amount;
                                                fseek(fp, -size, SEEK_CUR);
                                                fwrite(&f, size, 1, fp);
                                                break;
                                        }
                                    }
                        }
                                    if(flag==0)
                                    {
                                            printf("Sorry! Invalid Roll No.");
                                            getch();
                                    }
                        printf("Deposit More Amount!");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        tmp=getche();
                }
                break;
            case '4':
            tmp='Y';
            while(tmp=='Y'||tmp=='y')
            {
                        printf("\nEnter Roll Number to check Pending Amount");
                        scanf("%d", &r_no1);
                        printf("\nEnter the Stream");
                        scanf("%s", &stream1);
                        rewind(fp);
                        flag=0;
                        while(fread(&f, size, 1, fp))
                        {

                                    if((f.r_no==r_no1)&&(strcmp(f.stream,stream1)))
                                    {flag=1;
                                                pending=total-f.d_fee;
                                                printf("\nYour pending amount is: %ld", pending);

                                                getch();
                                    }
                        }
                        if(flag==0)
                        {
                                    printf("Sorry! Invalid Roll Number");
                                    getch();
                        }

                        fflush(stdin);
                        tmp=getche();
            }
            break;

            case '5':
            tmp='Y';
            while(tmp=='Y'||tmp=='y')
            {
                        printf("\nEnter Roll Number to delete");
                        scanf("%d",&r_no1);
                        ft = fopen("TEMP.txt","w");
                        rewind(fp);
                        while(fread(&f, size, 1, fp))
                        {
                                    if(f.r_no!=r_no1)
                                    fwrite(&f, 1, size, ft);
                        }
                        fclose(fp);
                        fclose(ft);
                        remove("FEES.txt");
                        rename("TEMP.txt", "FEES.txt");
                        fp=fopen("FEES.txt", "r");
                        printf("Delete another record(Y/N)");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        tmp = getche();
            }
            break;

            case '0':
            fclose(fp);
            printf("\n\t\tProgram Terminated!!");
            exit(0);
     }
}}
```

Okay, as suggested, I used fprintf() instead of fwrite(), and now I get this force close on my program. Here's the change I made: 
case '1':

```
        tmp = 'Y';
        while((tmp == 'Y') || (tmp == 'y'))
        {
                    printf("\n\tEnter Roll No: ");
                    scanf("%f", &f.r_no);
                    printf("\n\tEnter Name: ");
                    scanf(" %s", f.name);
                    printf("\n\tEnter Address: ");
                    scanf(" %s", f.add);
                    printf("\n\tEnter Father Name: ");
                    scanf(" %s", f.f_name);
                    printf("\n\tEnter Deposited Fee: ");
                    scanf("%f", &f.d_fee);
                    printf("\n\tEnter Stream: ");
                    scanf(" %s", f.stream);
                    fprintf(fp, "%d %s %s %s %f %s \n", f.r_no, f.name, f.add, f.f_name, f.d_fee, f.stream);
                    printf("\nCreate Another Student Record(Y/N)");
                    tmp = getche();
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Use `fprintf` instead of `fwrite`.

Comment: Writing a structure to a file doesn't convert it to text, it just writes the raw bytes of the structure. You need to format each field as you want it, using `fprintf()`.

Comment: Oh, also. Your code is very messy and difficult to read. You might want to improve your coding style to make your programs easier to debug.

Comment: I would make a separate procedure for each of the options to make the code a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

You are not writing a *text* file but a binary file, you can't inspect it's content with a plain text editor. You could with a HEX editor and some of them even accept defining a struct to verify the file record by record if you need to.

Or you need to write a read function that reads the binary data directly into an instance of your structure. Then print each member of the structure according to it's type.

Note that the `"w"` mode is for text files though, you should be using `"wb"` instead.

Comment: I think he wants to write text, not binary.

Comment: Perhaps, But I think this explains why inspecting the file with a text editor gives the result it does.

Comment: Yes I want to write a text file and not a binary file, if you could elaborate how do I write the information into a text file properly.

Comment: Thank you..! I'll give it a try!

Comment: You also want to keep each record of a fixed size so that you can easily randomly access it (i.e. start or record position = record number * some fixed value)